# Do we still need the "functional" tag?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Take a look at the questions with the [functional](/questions/tagged/functional) tag.  In my opinion, most of them should be re-tagged with [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming).  Functional-programming is much larger, has a nice wiki page, and is less ambiguous.  The few questions which wouldn't be appropriate for [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) fit nicely under more specific tags such as [functional-testing](/questions/tagged/functional-testing).

Comment: Then create a tag synonym request and let people upvote it.

Comment: Created a tag synonym request: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/functional-programming/synonyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what [functional](/questions/tagged/functional) is supposed to be about, and considering the wide range of questions that use it, no one seems to know. Nuke it!

Possible meanings include plain noise, [function](/questions/tagged/function), [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming), [functional-dependencies](/questions/tagged/functional-dependencies), [purely-functional](/questions/tagged/purely-functional) (or [immutable](/questions/tagged/immutable)), and undoubtedly more.

While you're at it, [non-functional](/questions/tagged/non-functional) can probably go too.